# Pass JSON data from Javascript File to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

It's been hours, I have been trying my best to pass the data that I have gathered, from JavaScript to Flask through Ajax query. 
  It seems to alright to me but when I am trying to fetch the data from Flask & printing it to cmd, getting None value.

```js
var input_data = {
    'application_data' : application_data,
    'oos_data' : oos_data,
    'vendor_data' : vendor_data,
    'infrastructure_data' : infrastructure_data
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    
    $.ajax({
        url : '/process',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify(input_data),
        contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",  
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        }
    })

});
```

application_data, oos_data, vendor_data, infrastructure_data --- All are list 
 
"submit" --- Button ID name which is button in form element of type=submit 
 
I want to pass the input_data to Flask application when submitting the form.

Below is the code in Flask, tried to retrieve...

```
     data = request.form.get('application_data')
     print('Data from JSON',data)
```

Tried with below code as well....

```
    data = request.get_json()
    print('Data from JSON',data)
```

output I received in cmd -- **Data from JSON None**  
It would very helpful to me if anyone can point out my mistake by giving right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `input_data` is set properly in the Javascript? Have you tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(input_data));` Check that is not empty.

Comment: I have tried to log the input_data as well. It has the value in it. :(